# Higher level language vs lower level language?

Tags: programming-languages

Other than the speed, what are the advantages/differences to each? i.e. can assembly do more than c/c++, or what advantages does java offer that python does not (excluding the fact that java is platform independent)?

Comment: Almost every programming language is [Turing-machine equivalent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine) and thus of "equal power". Whether or not one or another makes your life easier is another matter completely.

Comment: @Sarnold I think he/she was trying to find the advantages in how each differs in syntax and data structures. For example, Python has tuples and dictionaries, java does not.

Comment: @nmagerko: Java just makes you type one hundred times more to get to dictionaries. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A higher level programming language usually means that the programmer can be more abstract, and generally do less work, at the cost of fine control.

For example, programming a GUI in assembly would suicidal. On the other hand, machine code *is* necessary when you want to take advantage of device-dependent optimizations and features. I guess you can define that low-level languages as those that are used for low-level tasks, e.g. drivers, operating systems, and parsers. Of course, the definitions are always rather fuzzy.

Comment: _Suicide_ or [path to fame and fortune](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demoscene).

Comment: Well, demos are noninteractive :P

Answer (score 0):

Pretty broad question there, and I cannot answer for the specifics between python and java, but in general here's my thoughts... keep in mind, this is nearly a philosophical question (perhaps even best suited for the Programmers stackexchange group) so there's no god-like answer. here goes:

with low level languages (the closer you get to bit flipping), you tend to be closer to the system hardware and core operating system... resources are more explicitly manipulable... this makes for efficient programming in that you can streamline your logic, skim off the bundled crap you don't need and develop the perfect piece of code... the consequence is that it's usually harder to think in and thus code in.

higher level languages provide abstraction, moving the developer away from the worries of 1s and 0s to focus on more complex requirements of a system. they allow us to think about things closer to the semantics of human communication and thought. they also allow us to share work cross-platform sometimes when programmers work in high level languages that compile to common run-times. there are numerous other reasons, but you get the gist.

*ultimately I look at low level languages as something to use to "make the best tool", and high level languages to "make the best use of the best tools"*